# gnu-make: should I quote the contents of ifeq statements?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I recently came across this construct:

```
ifneq ("$(findstring needle, $(HAYSTACK))", "")
  do_some_stuff
endif
```

Is there really a use to the quotes or can I safely omit them ?

**EDIT:**

Just found out that: `ifeq ("a b ", "a b ")` behaves differently than `ifeq (a b , a b )`

The first one matches, not the second one. So the quotes are important indeed. Now the question is why.

Answer (score 3):

Humph, more badly documented make and its simple minded parsing. This seems similar to the way make parses variable assignment. So, using `␣` for a space,

```
VAR␣␣:=␣␣␣hello␣␣there␣
```

assigns `hello␣␣there␣` to `${VAR}`. Whitespace from around the `:=` is stripped, but any other is not. We could have written

```
VAR:=hello␣␣there␣#Pithy␣comment
```

and achieved the same result.

Similarly, whitespace is stripped from around the `,` in the `ifeq` statement.

```
ifeq ("a b ", "a b ")
```

compares the two literal strings `"a␣b␣"` (yes, the `"` characters form part of the text that is compared). Knowing this we find that the first non-whitespace either side of the comma are important. We could write

```
ifeq␣(!␣a␣b␣:␣␣␣,␣!␣a␣b␣:)
```

which successfully compares the two `!␣a␣b␣:` strings.

P.S. this explains why `ifeq (a b , a b )` fails. It attempts to compare `a␣b` and `a␣b␣`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb and say:

**They are equivalent to nothing and you can safely omit them.**

(Now watch the creator of GNUMake show up and say that if you try that when `HAYSTACK` contains a double-escaped unicode Sanscrit triple-quote your processor will catch fire.)

**EDIT:

Dammit, dammit, dammit!** They do matter. Just try playing around with `HAYSTACK := $(shell echo bang)`. You'd better have a fire extinguisher handy.

Comment: does not change much to me:

`HAYSTACK := $(shell echo bang)`
`ifeq ($(findstring needle, $(HAYSTACK)), )` 
looks similar to 
`ifeq ("$(findstring needle, $(HAYSTACK))", "")`
Do I miss somthing ?

Comment: @mbonnin, those two look the same, but they're different from `ifeq ("$(findstring needle, $(HAYSTACK))", )` and `ifeq ($(findstring needle, $(HAYSTACK)), "")`, because `"$(findstring needle, $(HAYSTACK))"` isn't the same as `$(findstring needle, $(HAYSTACK))`.

Comment: sure, from what I understand, the double quotes have no special meaning so adding them encloses the expression into arbitrary chars. I understand that adding them on one side and not on the other is a problem. But what about adding them on both sides. Is it any different from no quoting at all ?

Comment: @mbonnin, I'm pretty sure adding quotes on both sides makes no difference, but then I though adding them to one side would make no difference.

Comment: even adding them on both sides makes a difference. See my edit in the original question: `ifeq ("a b ", "a b ")` behaves differently than `ifeq (a b , a b )`